# How do I redefine a fill attribute in SVG using the set tag? I thought I knew, but

Tags: svg

I am working with the standard blank map 6 svg from wikimedia commons. I added a list of languages and I am trying to make it so that when I hover over a language the corresponding countries light up, change colour, or in some way indicate that they are 'selected'. Here is the code I am using.

```
<set 
attributeName="fill" 
 from="#E0E0E0" 
 to="#FF8888" 
begin="tEnglish.mouseover" 
end="tEnglish.mouseout" 
/>
```

where tEnglish is the text object that says 'English'. No luck.

Whether with  or  or any other method, I can not get the svg to change an attribute that has been defined. Meaning that if I delete the fill="#E0E0E0" attribute from one of the s, I can get it to work (altho then the default is black instead of grey, which does not fit the style of the website I'm working on), but if the  already contains a fill= attribute, it will not change as directed by the  tag.
I have also tried deleting the fill="#E0E0E0" and defining it in a stylesheet - same problem.

So, is it completely impossible to redefine an attribute of a path once it is declared? Does  only work if the attribute has not been defined elsewhere? Is my idea even possible? I appreciate any help that can be proffered.

I would also welcome any suggestions as to other methods (jquery, javascript) that you might have; although I am not so experienced with any of them I can do some research, any lead is appreciated.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you add `attributeType="CSS"`?

Comment: Is the element with id="tEnglish" in the svg file or is it in another document?

Comment: Could you take a look to my answer ? Was it what you are looking for ? If not, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put the `set` tag inside the element:

```
<rect
   width="248.57143"
   height="225.71428"
   x="137.14285"
   y="395.21933"
   id="myrect"
   style="fill:#800000;">
    <set 
        attributeName="fill" 
         to="#008000" 
        begin="mouseover" 
        end="mouseout" 
        />
</rect>
```

You can also achieve it using simple CSS:

```
#myrect {
    fill: #800000;
}

#myrect:hover {
    fill: #008000;
}
```

Example with css: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7dcnZ/2/

Of course, JavaScript is also an option:

```
$('#myrect').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('fill', '#008000');
}, 
function() {
    $(this).css('fill', '#800000');
});
```

Example with JavaScript: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7dcnZ/3/